# python app engine dev_appserver is unavailable (1.7.6)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, dev-appserver

Although the log says the dev_appserver has started browsers can't connect to it.

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=9090 --admin_port=9000
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2013-03-28 02:00:05,042 devappserver2.py:401] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-03-28 02:00:05,049 api_server.py:328] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
WARNING  2013-03-28 02:00:05,054 simple_search_stub.py:976] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/rc/x4y8pzk14x96nxmk7l66btv00000gn/T/appengine.example.user123/search_indexes
INFO     2013-03-28 02:00:05,056 api_server.py:152] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49602
INFO     2013-03-28 02:00:05,078 dispatcher.py:98] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:9090
INFO     2013-03-28 02:00:05,084 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:9000
```

I can't even reach the SDK console. I changed ports, I deleted the /var/folders/../weirdfolder multiple times and still I can't get it to work.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9064
Issue is related to latest chrome upgrade

How to fix:

go to chrome://flags and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser"